# Android onCreate not firing on new activity

Tags: android

Hi there I am trying to execute some code when I change to the next activity, but it does not seem to work. The Previous activity is a login page if the user is already logged in it goes straight to the new activity. But the onCreate does not seem to fire.

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private View mMainView;
    private Meteor mMeteor;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("ACTIVITY");
        Log.d("SimpleActivity","OnCreate Started");

        if(MeteorSingleton.getInstance().isConnected()){
            Log.d("Connection", "Connected");
        }else{
            Log.d("Connection", "Not Connected");
        }

        }

        ........
```

The strange thing is the setTitle works but none of the logs.

Here is some code from the previous login in page.

```
    @Override
    public void onConnect(boolean signedInAutomatically) {
        Log.i("Connection", "Connected to host server");
        if (mMeteor.isLoggedIn()) {
            openMainScreen(mLoginFormView);
        }
    }



     public void openMainScreen(View view) {
        Intent dashboard = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(dashboard);
    }
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="system.carproject.adam.ams">

    <!-- To auto-complete the email text field in the login form with the user's emails -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PROFILE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="Activity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

If someone could educate me on this would be great. Can seem to figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you are on the Debug mode in your logcat? There is a dropdown list you can choose your log mode from

Comment: `Android onCreate not firing on new activity` very strange title !, this does not even states your question! If you see the `activity` then the `onCreate ` is called. if your code is not working then debug and see why! and If you expect the `activity` to appear and it did not then also debug and see why or post more code for people to help you !

Comment: i agree with blueware, check if you are setting logcat to debug mode when running the application

Comment: Hi everyone thanks for the replys. I do have the logcat on debug mode. All the logs work fine on the previous activity. @AtefHares Sorry for the bad title you are right. I am pretty new to all this. But thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have created two `LAUNCHER` Activities and that's created two App Icon in your Device so if you think its open directly `MainActvity` then its possible if you click on second app icon in your device for same application . check your device .

first remove `LAUNCHER`  mode from `MainActvity` in Android Manifest and then you have to add manual check in your login `Activity` `onCreate()` for login status and then `startActvity()` `MainActivty` if login `status` is true.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the intent filter tag from activity tag of MainActivity in Manifest:-

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
  android:label="Activity"> </activity>
```

Comment: If I remove this it cant find the main activity and crashes

Comment: remove only intent filter tag inside the activity tag, not the whole activity tag